# Nomenclature Issue - What is the origin of the term 'steering vector' in beamforming?

Tags: beamforming

I am new to telecom and developed an interest in beamforming. I've read about its basics [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=665) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128188033/machine-learning), and was intrigued with the name "steering vector".

It is clear to me that the steering vector is constant and depicts the complex amplitudes and phases that each sensor of an array exhibits when receiving a signal from a specific direction. But it does not "steer" the beam or anything else; actually, it is a feature of the array as a whole - so, what the name for?

Now, the weights vector represents the complex parameters assigned to each sensor in the array to achieve the desired beamforming behavior - including, of course, steering the beam.

In conclusion, the term "steering vector" sounds counterintuitive given that the "weights vector" is what actually controls the direction of the beam. So, what the steering vector steers? For a newbie, this is a confusing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you 'steer' an old style parabolic reflector radar antenna, by physically turning it, you provide it with a direction to look in.

If the 'steering vector' for a phased array actually steers anything, it steers the efforts of a person or algorithm (a similar but slightly different use of the same metaphor) to find a weights vector that will make it 'look' in that direction.